# Windows: How to compile WPF XAML-based program from command line?

Tags: visual-studio-express

I'm not very impressed with Visual Studio Express 2013, which is the free version of Visual Studio. I would greatly prefer to just compile my C# program form the command line. I've located the compiler csc.exe and I located the DLL files for .NET, but how can I compile a XAML file?

Comment: I attempted to answer your question below. Just out of curiosity, why do you not like VS? It is generally regarded as one of the better IDEs.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use MSBuild ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171452%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)). This is the standard way to compile .NET projects from command line. This is also the compiler that Visual Studio uses internally. You have to have a .csproj/.sln file for it to work, but it will be the fastest and most effective way to get to where it sounds like you want to be.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for [MSBuild](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd393574.aspx). Visual Studio projects are XML scripts for MSBuild. To build a project or solution, you can use the following commands:

```
MSBuild MyApp.sln
MSBuild MyApp.csproj
```

Building XAML files is far from trivial and C# compiler isn't enough for this. The most recent MSBuild targets for XAML is in the `C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Xaml.targets` file. But doing all this manually isn't the best idea, you'll just overcomplicate things even if you manage to do everything without MSBuild.